# Derivative of $u(x) = x^T x$

Tags: reference-request

I would like a book that explains how to take the derivative of a function that maps vectors to vectors. Specifically, I would like a book that explains multi-variable differentiation, the multi-variable product rule, and the multi-variable integration by parts.

Here is a simple example of the type of problem I would like to be able to solve with the information in this book:
Let $u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u(x) = x^T x$. Find the derivative of u with respect to $x$.

You'd think this material would be in books entitled 'Multivariable Calculus', but I haven't found a book with that title that explains it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $u (x) = x^T x$ is a scalar-valued function, not a vector-valued function.

Comment: Depending on whether $x$ is a column or row vector, $x^tx$ will be a $1\times1$ or $n\times n$ matrix (respectively), so your codomain for the map $u$ is incorrect. Interestingly, I *would* think any book entitled multivariable calculus (or even any comprehensive Calculus book, which should include multivariable calculus) would have it, and I wonder about what kind of book(s) you've looked at.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with $x^t x$? Multiplying the vector with its $t$-th component? (BTW, you should use LaTeX formatting; in this case, it would just mean to surround your formulas by dollar signs.)

Comment: @RodCarvalho: Your edit changed the lower-case into an uppercase $T$. Now it reads as a transpose. Which may or may not be what user24205 meant. The fact that this way $u(x)$ doesn't map to $\mathbb R^n$ speaks against this interpretation.

Comment: @celtschk: You're totally right. However, the OP can re-edit if he disagrees with my interpretation of his post.

Answer (score 1):

The map $$\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:x\rightarrow xx^{t}$$ gives $(x_{1}...x_{n})\rightarrow \sum x_{i}^{2}$. So the partial derivative with respect to $x_{i}$ is $2x_{i}$, and the total derivative is $2x$. However if you are viewing $x$ as $n\times 1$ matrix and $x^{t}$ as $1\times n$ matrix, then you have a block $n\times n$ matrix whose $j$'th column is $xx_{j}$ and $i$-th row is $xx_{i}$. Since we have dealing with spaces of $n$ and $n^{2}$ dimensions respectively, you would expect the derivative matrix to be in $\mathbb{R}^{n^{3}}$ by specifying each $f_{ij}=x_{i}x_{j}$'s derivative at $x_{k}$ ($0$ when $i,j\not=k$, $x_{i},x_{j}$ otherwise).

The most general way to deal with this is through tensors. But this kind of exercise is standard. I am teaching calculus this semester, and this seems not in Stewart, so taking a look at some analysis texts (like Rudin) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

## Hint

You may find derivative mapping $D{u}$ immediately, using definition:
$u$ is called differentiable, if $\Delta u=u(x+h)-u(x)$ may be represented as

$$u(x+h)-u(x)=Du(x)h+\alpha(x,\,h),$$
where $Du(x)$ is linear mapping $Du(x): \; \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha$ satisfies $$|| \alpha(x,\,h) ||=o(||h||).$$
Extraction *linear* part from  $\Delta u$ gives desired derivative.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with commenters that any multivariable calculus book ought to cover this sort of problem, but in case your books have been a bit too elementary, perhaps focused on the 2 or 3 variable cases, I'd recommend Hubbard & Hubbard Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms for an introduction to what you need for this problem and much more.